# How to protect WYSIWYG against XSS attacks

Tags: php, html, xss, wysiwyg

I am using a WYSIWYG editor and I am trying to allow safe html attributes such as `<table><a><img><strong>` etc while still preventing XSS. I *thought* that using a combination of HTML purifier and and whitelisting tags would do the trick.

Here is my sanitation:

```
function strip_tags_wysiwyg($string){
    include_once '../includes/htmlpurifier-4.5.0/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($string);
    $clean_html=strip_tags($clean_html,"<a><address><em><strong><b><i><big><small><sub><sup><cite><code><img><ul><ol><li><dl><lh><dt><dd><br><p><table><th><td><tr><pre><blockquote><nowiki><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><hr>");

    return $clean_html;
}
```

Today, someone showed me that I was still vulnerable when they put this HTML in:

```
<img src="x" onerror="alert(0)">
```

What suggestions do you guys have for further securing my code? Thanks!

EDIT: Obviously I am running PHP, so a PHP solution would be ideal.

Comment: Strip out all attributes that can have code in them (on*, href="javascript:* , ...) . Or use a white list for allowed attributes .